# Unable to determine if resource XXXX exists in http://download.java.net/maven/2

Tags: maven

Our builds generate a lot of errors like:

Unable to determine if resource XXXX exists in http://download.java.net/maven/2

I know this repository is gone, but I cannot locate the reference to it.  If I look at the effective POM using Eclipse, the only repositories other than our internal one are:

http://repo1.maven.org/maven2
http://public.dhe.ibm.com/ibmdl/export/pub/software/websphere/wasdev/maven/repository

and the pluginRepository is

https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2

The errors does break anything, but it would be nice for them to go away.   Any ideas on what might be referencing this java.net URL?  Perhaps some Maven plugin?